# Changing msExchRequireAuthToSendTo on AD group back to "Not Set"

Tags: powershell, email, active-directory, powershell-4.0

We run a "hybrid" Exchange environment where Office365 looks at some attributes on AD groups.  One of the ExtendedAttributes, **msExchRequireAuthToSendTo**, controls whether or not an "outside" user can send to a distribution list held in AD.

This ExtendedAttribute has three possible settings: True / False / "Not Set" - in order to prevent "outside" users from sending spam, the value has to be True.  The default is "Not Set".

I can set either True or False like this:

```
$InternalDistro = (Get-ADGroup -filter 'name -eq "CoolDistroList"')
Set-ADGroup $InternalDistro -Replace @{msExchRequireAuthToSendTo = $False}
```

Is there a way to set the value BACK to the default value of "Not Set"?  I tried $Null but that returns an error:

```
Set-ADGroup : Cannot bind parameter 'Replace' to the target. Exception setting "Replace": "Object reference not set to an 
instance of an object."
At line:2 char:38
+ ... ADGroup $InternalDistro -Replace @{msExchRequireAuthToSendTo = $Null}
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Set-ADGroup], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADGroup
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated - thanks for thinking about this!

Comment: Is there a purpose to setting it back to 'Not Set' rather than 'False'? If so use the `-Clear` parameter: `Set-ADGroup $InternalDistro -Clear 'msExchRequireAuthToSendTo'`

Comment: Thanks @TheMadTechnician, that works perfectly!

The thought was just to keep the values in that field as "true" for internal lists or "not set" for all others, instead of having a mix of three values and having to interpret that "false and "not set" have the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a purpose to setting it back to 'Not Set' rather than
>   'False'? If so use the -Clear parameter: Set-ADGroup $InternalDistro
>   -Clear 'msExchRequireAuthToSendTo' – TheMadTechnician

This works perfectly, posting as the answer - all credit to @TheMadTechnician!